# Cannot export template function

Tags: c++, templates, dllexport

I have a class named "SimObject":

```
namespace simBase
{
    class __declspec(dllexport) SimObject: public SimSomething
    {
        public:

            template <class T>
            void updateParamValue( const std::string& name, T val );
    }
}
```

I have another class named "ITerrainDrawable":

```
namespace simTerrain
{
    class __declspec(dllexport) ITerrainDrawable : public simBase::SimObject
    {
    }
}
```

These classes are in different libraries. SimObject is in simBase, ITerrainDrawable is in simTerrain libraries. Even if ITerrainDrawable is derived from SimObject and I included library of simBase, I get a link error:

> unresolved external symbol

```
1>ITerrainDrawable.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall simBase::SimObject::updateParamValue<float>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,float)" (??$updateParamValue@M@SimObject@simBase@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@M@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall simTerrain::ITerrainDrawable::setTerrainSize(float)" (?setTerrainSize@ITerrainDrawable@simTerrain@@QAEXM@Z)
1>ITerrainDrawable.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall simBase::SimObject::updateParamValue<class osg::Vec4f>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class osg::Vec4f)" (??$updateParamValue@VVec4f@osg@@@SimObject@simBase@@QAEXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@VVec4f@osg@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall simTerrain::ITerrainDrawable::setSatelliteTextureBorders(class osg::Vec2f,class osg::Vec2f)" (?setSatelliteTextureBorders@ITerrainDrawable@simTerrain@@QAEXVVec2f@osg@@0@Z)
```

Why do I get this error?

Everything works fine if I don't use template function but I need it.

If I move this function to simTerrain library it works fine but I don't want to use duplicate function because there are many libraries like simTerrain.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++ does not really support the separate compilation of template code - you need to put the definition of the template in a header file.

Comment: thanks Neil :) it worked when i move the function definition to the header

Answer (score 5):

The full implementation of a template class must be in that template class's header. The ANSI/ISO standards for C++ allow for a way to put the implementation in a separate compilation unit using the **export** keyword , but there are currently any compilers that actually support this.

For more information read [this](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401563) and [this.](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill23-x.htm)

Comment: i use VisualStudio2008 and the response to export is : warning C4237: 'export' keyword is not yet supported, but reserved for future use

Answer (score 5):

There are two compilation model for templates :

1. Inclusion compilation model  ( like including header file )
2. Separate compilation model  ( separation of interface from implementation )

You can use **export keyword** at time of template definition for 2nd option.

```
export template <class T>
void updateParamValue( const std::string& name, T val ) {}
```

But I am not sure that all compiler supports it.

Comment: i use VisualStudio2008 and the response to export is : 
warning C4237: 'export' keyword is not yet supported, but reserved for future use

Comment: vc++ 7.0 does not support it , may be next version might have support of it.
But I run it on linux GNU C++ 8.2 compiler which supports it.

Comment: i wish your answer be true but stupid vs does not support it yet :/ 

i dont like to write function definitions to header.

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify (cpp file is fine) template specialization. It means you need to export all combination of template arguments, you are going to use:

```
template __declspec(dllexport) void updateParamValue<int>( const std::string& name, T val );
template __declspec(dllexport) void updateParamValue<short>( const std::string& name, T val );
......
```

I use this in Visual Studio 2013 and it works.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the working example:

```
template<class T> TEST_API void foo(T)
{
    std::cout << "test";
}

template TEST_API void foo(int);
template TEST_API void foo(char);
```

Dump of file test.dll

File Type: DLL

Section contains the following exports for test.dll

```
00000000 characteristics
4FDEF629 time date stamp Mon Jun 18 12:34:33 2012
    0.00 version
       1 ordinal base
       3 number of functions
       3 number of names

ordinal hint RVA      name

      1    0 00001032 ??$foo@D@@YAXD@Z = @ILT+45(??$foo@D@@YAXD@Z)
      2    1 00001014 ??$foo@H@@YAXH@Z = @ILT+15(??$foo@H@@YAXH@Z)
```

Comment: You need to add TEST_API only with template instantiations. Otherwise there is a compile error (C2491)